# Need a way to iterate over XML using xmldoc

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, mongodb

Using Appery.io javascript server side code. Basically a MongoDB.

Libraries being used xmldoc.js 0.1.2 & sax.js 0.5.4

Additional libraries available: Underscore.js 1.5.1 moment.js 2.1.0 Handlebars.js 1.0.0

Using the code below I am able to access a the first single node value I need and insert that one item into the database but I need to way to continue iterating over the xml and continue creating the objects in the database. I would prefer to send this in 1 API call if possible but I don't think it is. Is there a way to iterate over via a loop or something that will "skip" the previously sent items. There is only about 20 results from the url below.

```
var XHRResponse = XHR2.send("GET",'http://www.bing.com/news?q=Politics&FORM=NSBABR&FORMAT=RSS', {});


var Bingresult = new XmlDocument(XHRResponse.body);

var link = Bingresult.valueWithPath("channel.item.link");

var title = Bingresult.valueWithPath("channel.item.title");

var source = Bingresult.valueWithPath("channel.item.News:Source");

var news_image = Bingresult.valueWithPath("channel.item.News:Image");

var pub_date = Bingresult.valueWithPath("channel.item.pubDate");


//response.success(Bingresult, "Rss"); Same as console.log//


Collection.createObject("55d3d209e4b0d6ee27c97867", "News_", {"link": link,"title": title, "source": source,"news_image": news_image, "pub_date": pub_date})._id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code below and it worked for me:

```
var XHRResponse = XHR2.send("GET",'http://www.bing.com/news?q=Politics&FORM=NSBABR&FORMAT=RSS', {});

var Bingresult = new XmlDocument(XHRResponse.body);

// Pull out the <channel> node
var channel = Bingresult.childNamed("channel");

// Filter out only 'item' children
var items = channel.childrenNamed("item");
console.log("Found %s items.", items.length);

// Loop through each item
items.forEach(function(item) {
   var title = item.valueWithPath("title");         
   var link = item.valueWithPath("link");
   var source = item.valueWithPath("News:Source");
   var news_image = item.valueWithPath("News:Image");
   var pub_date = item.valueWithPath("pubDate");

   // Print values - you can add them to db here       
   console.log("\nTitle '%s' \nLink '%s' \nSource '%s' \nImage '%s' \nDate '%s'", title, link, source, news_image, pub_date);
}
```

Example of what is printed (I am putting just one entry here, the code actually prints several entries like this, one each news)

```
Title 'Bernie Sanders Right at Home in Democratic Party' 
Link 'http://www.bing.com/news/apiclick.aspx?ref=FexRss&aid=&tid=08F7562EF23642259F2CE9F19679C141&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.ammoland.com%2f2015%2f10%2fbernie-sanders-right-at-home-in-democratic-party%2f&c=_Lbqne5iN09in8HqtFhw6GS0tbEY8KpchXOcT_gmFmA&mkt=en-us' 
Source 'Ammo Land' 
Image 'http://a2.bing4.com/th?id=ON.032A87B845B1305FEC6642A06226A671&pid=News' 
Date 'Fri, 16 Oct 2015 15:59:00 GMT'
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain the last line to me in the print value section? I have no concept of whats going on with the %s and /n notation.

Comment: %s is used to substitute string values, so Title %s will print Title <title of news>. \n will move output to a new line. This is just a way to format the output to console.

Comment: I will add an example of what is printed with the sentence in the last line.